# Import google plus friend list using php

Tags: google-plus

Could any one give me suggestion on how to get `friend list on google plus` using PHP.
Is there any **plugin or widget** to do this.It would be great to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs to grant your app access to this information via the OAuth 2.0 scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` and then you can use the REST API or client libraries to get the list of friends.

See the [Google+ PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php) for a sample application that accomplishes all of the steps necessary for what you want to do. The sample uses the Symfony framework to keep the code concise, but you should be able to take away how to do the same in your own PHP environment.

Also, see the [Google APIs PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) that you can use in your project. This library is embedded in the quickstart via composer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it would retrieve the people visible to the app. Am i right? I am seeking help for retrieving people of my circle.

Comment: Correct and that is the only list of people that you can get API access to.